# SQL Table Column null even after adding default

Tags: sql, alter

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TitleCodeInformation 
    ADD CommissionPercentage INT 
    DEFAULT 100 
    CHECK (CommissionPercentage >= 0 AND CommissionPercentage <= 100)
```

Here is my SQL statement. I'm still finding that this value is null. Would there be any reasons for this?

Maybe it's only on new records that get created?

Comment: `maybe its only on new records that get created?` How about giving this idea a try?

Comment: If the column is nullable, default being added later will not default existing records (sql server). Also, tag your dbms in case oracle or mysql are different or something.

Comment: If thats the case why dont you do an update statement that fixes existing records

Comment: Will do thanks buddy